# Adjustable and multi-line label in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to write a canvas graph application by using HTML5 and JavaScript. The main element in this app is a box that the user is able to write a long text in it and the size of the  box should adjust while writing the text. I realized that the best way is to use the textarea tag while the user wants to write in it and when the user loses the focus(blur event) on the textarea it will change to a label with the same value in the textarea. You can see the related code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html public "-//w3c//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TB/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Editable Label</title>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="box.css">-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#txt').blur(function () {
                if ($('#txt').val().trim() != '') {
                    $('#txt').hide();
                    $('#lbl').html($('#txt').val());
                    $('#txt').val('');
                }
            });

            $('#lbl').click(function () {

                if ($('#lbl').html().trim() != '') {

                    $('#txt').show();

                    $('#txt').val($('#lbl').html());

                    $('#lbl').html('');
                }
            });
        });


    </script>
</head>
<body>


    <div id="container" align="center" style="width:1300px; height:700px; position:relative;">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1300px" height="700px" style="border: 1px solid #323232;" ></canvas>
        <span id="lbl" style="color: #ff0000; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; position:absolute; top:200px; left:170px;"></span>
        <textarea id="txt" type="text" style="position:absolute; top:200px; left:170px;"></textarea>

    </div>




</body>
</html>
```

I could make the textbox appear in multi-line by using textarea tag instead of the input tag but the problem is that I don't know how to make the label to appear in multi-line. I searched a lot and already used `white-space:normal;` and `display:inline-block;` and `width: 20px;` in styling the label but it didn't work. I am wondering if I need to adjust the label size (width and height) by using Jquery. If yes, how exactly do I have to do that?
Note that since the user is entering unknown amount of words I cannot use line breaking tags.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: For html5 your Doctype should simply be `<!doctype html>`

Comment: You've also got an extra double-quote in there: ";" ></canvas>

Comment: @Petty thanks I'll apply your advice but it does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is

overflow:hidden; or overflow:visible;

so:

```
<textarea id="txt" type="text" style="position:absolute; top:200px; left:170px; overflow:hidden;"></textarea>
```

It would be easier to read your code if you used CSS though.

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do then, `width:220px;` made the text break for me.  This also worked, and I believe it better matches what I think you're trying to do:

```
    #lbl{           
        max-width:220px;
        height:auto;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this. I have problem about the span tag and not about the textarea. Sorry about the css. I thought this way is easier.